# Running a script on a remote system without copying the script there

Tags: ssh, scripting, remote

I have a script on `server A`, I need to run that script on `server B` but I don't want to copy the script over to `server B`.

And i need to pass the text file as a argument to the script

How would I do that?

Comment: About your last edit: is it correct to say that you want your script to receive the name of a file as an argument and that that file is located on your local system? So, are you also trying to make that text file readable by your script without copying it (the text file) to the remote system beforehand? Or is the text file located on the remote system already?

Comment: yes you are correct ,text file is located in the local system and i want to read the text file without copying it to the remote host

Comment: Then I'd suggest you to ask a new questions, linking to this one to provide context. If possible/meaningful, I'd also suggest you to explain why you are trying to run a script on a remote system and also send it a file to be processed: other users may be able to propose alternative approaches or point out pitfalls in your current one.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply `cat` your script and pipe it to an ssh session:

```
cat /path/to/local/script.sh | ssh user@remote
```

That should work for most cases, but note that the script will be interpreted by your default login shell on the remote. If the script is written for another shell, this won't work.

Comment: dear @terdon for me i'm getting ubuntu greeting message with script output , and `-t -q` didn't help , is that something that should be configured separatly ? or exists a solution within ssh args|parametrs ?

Comment: @Jonah Probably `cat script.sh | ssh user@host sh -s arguments`, which also allows for arguments to be passed to the script and lets you choose the interpreter to run (here, `sh`; otherwise the script will be executed by the user's default shell (regardless of the shebang)). I haven't tested it on Ubuntu, though.

Comment: This is not working if i send the text file as a input argument to the script

Comment: @abdulrahuman what text file? What argument? How can we know you need to pass an argument if you don't say it in your question? Please edit your question and explain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

use function insteed !

convert your script to function and pass it with arguments.

in this way :

```
ssh user@host -tq "function foo(){ echo $*;}; foo hello world"
```

but writing a function each time as argument isn't practical.

to make things easy create a function that helps to call local function on remote machines.

```
foo () { 
    echo "${@}" 
}
bar () { 
    echo ${#} 
}

ssh_func() {
    ssh -tq user@host "function $(typeset -f ${1}); "  ${2:+"${@:2}"}; 
    # typeset -t (prints function's body chunk) to be sent with args
}
ssh_func foo hello world # this will call foo on remote machine
ssh_func bar hello world
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does and how it works?

Comment: @nohillside it will simply send the function to be evaluated before called on target machine , it's just like `ssh u@host "function foo(){ echo $*;}; foo hello world"`

Comment: I know what it does, future visitors may not. Adding such explanations to the answer will increase its value.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I've found personally is to base64, copy, decode then run. This ensures that 1) you don't need to create a file and make it executable on the remote host and 2) you won't have problems with encoding or funny characters. You can fairly easily expand this to interpreted languages (must be a self contained program).

`cat script.sh | base64 | ssh user@host "base64 -d - | bash"`

It's a bit spaghetti but the concept is there.

Comment: SSH should pass any binary data unmodified, so base64 encoding really shouldn't be necessary

Comment: that's fair, it's probably consequence of old habits and dealing with some corner cases...